# Where can I get the dataset of duplicates questions in Stack Overflow or StackEXchange

Tags: support, questions

Where can I get the dataset of duplicates questions in Stack Overflow or StackEXchange? Maybe somewhere in: https://archive.org/download/stackexchange

Comment: Those that have been closed as duplicates (source), or those that have questions closed as duplicates of them (target), or both?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries)? You can write your own query to extract content...

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279550/how-to-find-questions-closed-as-duplicates-via-the-data-explorer and that answer mentions PostHistory for type =10 and comment = 101, that would work for the datadump as well

Comment: Its not explained in the other post, but is it possible to get the pair of duplicate post? if postA is marked as duplicate, can we get the post that it is duplicated to